# Dependence of zeroes of a polynomial on polynomial's coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

[image]

What I have done so far:

Suppose $ \lambda $ is a root. Then,

$ \Lambda(p,q) = \lambda^2+p \lambda+q $. To prove that the zeros are $ C^1 $ functions, we need to prove that $ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial p} $ and $ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial q} $ are continuous.

This is where it gets confusing.

$ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial q} = \lambda $ and $ \frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial q} = 1 $.

These are constant functions so they are continuous. What am I missing here?

Also can someone give me hints for parts (b) and (c)? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Part (a)** You need to prove that $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial p}$ and $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial q}$ exist and are continuous i.e. $\lambda$ not $\Lambda$.

Note that, since $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial p}=-\frac{\lambda}{2\lambda+ p}$ and $2\lambda\ne -p$, the continuity is obvious.

**Part (b) Hint**

This is the same as part (a) for a polnomial of degree $n$ rather than degree $2$ and can be answered in the same way.

**Part (c) Hint**

Express the eigenvalue as a root of a polynomial equation.